# setting up existing laravel project in Ubuntu

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, phpmyadmin, object-oriented-database

How to setup existing ***laravel 5 project*** and there database in ***Ubuntu 14.04*** using xampp?

Comment: This should help https://bhavyanshu.me/tutorials/setup-laravel-project-on-xampp-linux/01/12/2015

Comment: its not down.i didn't find proper solution there thats why i post here.i mention there its existing project not how to create project in laravel.

Comment: @urni : you can read the steps I suggested , I can help you more if you got any issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of things you need to consider for new setup. If you have setup git repo then

1. You can just pull from git If not copy/paste all folders except `vendor`, `node_modules`.
2. Use `composer install` to make vendor folder
3. Use `npm install` to make node_modules folder if you already using
4. Use `php artisan migrate` to make database structure
5. Use `php artisan db:seed` if you set any seeding to fill tables data
6. Use `php artisan key:generate` to make security.
7. Create/Update `.env` file to make work configuration from environment

Now you have to point your domain with root folder of laravel you created here.

Comment: i already have laravel database sql file, i just want to import it in database.

Comment: better practice is to make migration and seed